# Stuck solving $\ln(e^y-1)-y=t+c$ for $y$

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I'm trying to solve for $y$

$\ln(e^y-1)-y=t+c$

$e^y-1=e^{(t+c+y)}$

$e^y=e^{(t+c+y)}+1$

$y=t+c+y+1$

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: last step is wrong.You took log on both sides. So rhs is 
$y=log\{e^{t+c+y}+1\}$

Comment: Not sure on why this has been downvoted? Perhaps the tag?

Comment: Difficult to know. Yes the tag could be better.

Comment: Hint: $e^{y}(1-e^{t+c})=1$

Comment: @Did Of course, that was what I meant.

Comment: @Did   Thanks. I removed the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking from your third step $$e^y = e^{t+c+y} + 1 \\ e^y - e^{t+c+y} =1 \\ e^y(1-e^{t+c}) = 1 \\ e^y = (1-e^{t+c})^{-1} \\ y = -\ln(1-e^{t+c})$$

Comment: This answer is so clear. I can see where I went wrong in a second. Awesome!